# Ubuntu 16.04 - enp2s0 became enp9s0 without hardware change - lost network

Tags: networking, server, lan

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04. This server gets rebooted few times a day due to one of my long running process failing and bash script recovering things, by simply doing reboot.

After few days of such a setup there is no networking, on start I get: "failed to start raise network interfaces". I've connected keyboard and screen, logged in to the machine and noticed that `/etc/network/interfaces` has reference to `enp2s0`, however `ifconfig` returns the `enp9so`. I've changed that in `/etc/network/interfaces` so it matches `enp9so` and rebooted server. It has worked, however I can't figure out why it has happened?

I am not sure if this helps, but all (3) machines in this LAN network had some network problems as well, I am not sure if they are victim or the cause of this issue.

Restarting the other machines didn't help. I had to restart the switch and the router that this switch is connected to.

Any idea why I am experiencing this issue? Thanks